# Efficiently re-indexing one level with "forward-fill" in a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
                          value
item_uid   created_at          

0S0099v8iI 2015-03-25  10652.79
0F01ddgkRa 2015-03-25   1414.71
0F02BZeTr6 2015-03-20  51505.22
           2015-03-23  51837.97
           2015-03-24  51578.63
           2015-03-25       NaN
           2015-03-26       NaN
           2015-03-27  50893.42
0F02BcIzNo 2015-03-17   1230.00
           2015-03-23   1130.00
0F02F4gAMs 2015-03-25   1855.96
0F02Vwd6Ou 2015-03-19   5709.33
0F04OlAs0R 2015-03-18    321.44
0F05GInfPa 2015-03-16    664.68
0F05PQARFJ 2015-03-18   1074.31
           2015-03-26   1098.31
0F06LFhBCK 2015-03-18    211.49
0F06ryso80 2015-03-16     13.73
           2015-03-20     12.00
0F07gg7Oth 2015-03-19   2325.70
```

I need to sample the full dataframe between two dates `start_date` and `end_date` on every date between them, propagating the last seen value. The sampling should be done within each `item_uid` independently/separately.

For example, if we were to sample between `2015-03-20` and `2015-03-29` for `0F02BZeTr6`, we should get:

```
0F02BZeTr6 2015-03-20  51505.22
           2015-03-21  51505.22
           2015-03-22  51505.22
           2015-03-23  51837.97
           2015-03-24  51578.63
           2015-03-25  51578.63
           2015-03-26  51578.63
           2015-03-27  50893.42
           2015-03-28  50893.42
           2015-03-29  50893.42
```

Note that I am forward filling both `NaN` **and** **missing entries** in the dataframe.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370084/sampling-with-the-most-recent-value) addresses a similar problem, but only with one group (i.e. one level). This question instead asks how to do the same but within each group (`item_uid`) separately. While I could split the input dataframe and iterate through each of the groups (each of the `item_uid`), and then stitch together the result, I am wondering if there is anything more efficient.

When I do the following (see [this PR](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9019)):

```
dates         = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)    
df.groupby(level='itemuid').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(dates, method='ffill'))
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Fill method not supported if level passed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a couple of options, the easiest IMO is to simply unstack the first level and then ffill. I think this make it much clearer about what's going on than a groupby/resample solution (I suspect it will also be faster, depending on the data):

```
In [11]: df1['value'].unstack(0)
Out[11]:
item_uid    0F01ddgkRa  0F02BZeTr6  0F02BcIzNo  0F02F4gAMs  0F02Vwd6Ou  0F04OlAs0R  0F05GInfPa  0F05PQARFJ  0F06LFhBCK  0F06ryso80  0F07gg7Oth  0S0099v8iI
created_at
2015-03-16         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      664.68         NaN         NaN       13.73         NaN         NaN
2015-03-17         NaN         NaN        1230         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-18         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      321.44         NaN     1074.31      211.49         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-19         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     5709.33         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      2325.7         NaN
2015-03-20         NaN    51505.22         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN       12.00         NaN         NaN
2015-03-23         NaN    51837.97        1130         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-24         NaN    51578.63         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-25     1414.71         NaN         NaN     1855.96         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN    10652.79
2015-03-26         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     1098.31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-27         NaN    50893.42         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

If you're missing some dates you have to reindex (assuming the start and end are present, otherwise you can do this manually e.g. with `pd.date_range`):

```
In [12]: df1['value'].unstack(0).asfreq('D')
Out[12]:
item_uid    0F01ddgkRa  0F02BZeTr6  0F02BcIzNo  0F02F4gAMs  0F02Vwd6Ou  0F04OlAs0R  0F05GInfPa  0F05PQARFJ  0F06LFhBCK  0F06ryso80  0F07gg7Oth  0S0099v8iI
2015-03-16         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      664.68         NaN         NaN       13.73         NaN         NaN
2015-03-17         NaN         NaN        1230         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-18         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      321.44         NaN     1074.31      211.49         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-19         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     5709.33         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      2325.7         NaN
2015-03-20         NaN    51505.22         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN       12.00         NaN         NaN
2015-03-21         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-22         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-23         NaN    51837.97        1130         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-24         NaN    51578.63         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-25     1414.71         NaN         NaN     1855.96         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN    10652.79
2015-03-26         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     1098.31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2015-03-27         NaN    50893.42         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

*Note: `asfreq` drops the name of the index (which is most likely a bug!)*

Now you can ffill:

```
In [13]: df1['value'].unstack(0).asfreq('D').ffill()
Out[13]:
item_uid    0F01ddgkRa  0F02BZeTr6  0F02BcIzNo  0F02F4gAMs  0F02Vwd6Ou  0F04OlAs0R  0F05GInfPa  0F05PQARFJ  0F06LFhBCK  0F06ryso80  0F07gg7Oth  0S0099v8iI
2015-03-16         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN      664.68         NaN         NaN       13.73         NaN         NaN
2015-03-17         NaN         NaN        1230         NaN         NaN         NaN      664.68         NaN         NaN       13.73         NaN         NaN
2015-03-18         NaN         NaN        1230         NaN         NaN      321.44      664.68     1074.31      211.49       13.73         NaN         NaN
2015-03-19         NaN         NaN        1230         NaN     5709.33      321.44      664.68     1074.31      211.49       13.73      2325.7         NaN
2015-03-20         NaN    51505.22        1230         NaN     5709.33      321.44      664.68     1074.31      211.49       12.00      2325.7         NaN
2015-03-21         NaN    51505.22        1230         NaN     5709.33      321.44      664.68     1074.31      211.49       12.00      2325.7         NaN
2015-03-22         NaN    51505.22        1230         NaN     5709.33      321.44      664.68     1074.31      211.49       12.00      2325.7         NaN
2015-03-23         NaN    51837.97        1130         NaN     5709.33      321.44      664.68     1074.31      211.49       12.00      2325.7         NaN
2015-03-24         NaN    51578.63        1130         NaN     5709.33      321.44      664.68     1074.31      211.49       12.00      2325.7         NaN
2015-03-25     1414.71    51578.63        1130     1855.96     5709.33      321.44      664.68     1074.31      211.49       12.00      2325.7    10652.79
2015-03-26     1414.71    51578.63        1130     1855.96     5709.33      321.44      664.68     1098.31      211.49       12.00      2325.7    10652.79
2015-03-27     1414.71    50893.42        1130     1855.96     5709.33      321.44      664.68     1098.31      211.49       12.00      2325.7    10652.79
```

and stack it back (Note: you can dropna=False if you want to include the starting NaN):

```
In [14]: s = df1['value'].unstack(0).asfreq('D').ffill().stack()
```

Note: If you the ordering of the index is important you can switch/sort it:

```
In [15]: s.index = s.index.swaplevel(0, 1)

In [16]: s = s.sort_index()

In [17]: s.index.names = ['item_uid', 'created_at']  # as this is lost earlier

In [18]: s
Out[18]:
item_uid
0F01ddgkRa  2015-03-25     1414.71
            2015-03-26     1414.71
            2015-03-27     1414.71
0F02BZeTr6  2015-03-20    51505.22
            2015-03-21    51505.22
            2015-03-22    51505.22
            2015-03-23    51837.97
            2015-03-24    51578.63
            2015-03-25    51578.63
            2015-03-26    51578.63
            2015-03-27    50893.42
...
0S0099v8iI  2015-03-25    10652.79
            2015-03-26    10652.79
            2015-03-27    10652.79
Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

Whether this is more efficient than a groupby/resample apply solution will depend on the data. For very sparse data (with lots of starting up NaN, assuming you want to drop these) I suspect it won't be as fast. If the data is dense (or you want to keep the initial NaN) I suspect this solution should be faster.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Very helpful! And the solution makes perfect sense. As for the `asfreq('D')` did you open a GitHub issue as a bug? Let me know otherwise, I can help with that.

Comment: Please [do](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) :) I haven't checked on master whether this is the still the case. But if so it hopefully should be an easy fix!