# Fill Missing Dates in DataFrame with Duplicate Dates in Groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a daily status count from the following DataFrame (it's a subset, the real data set is ~14k jobs with overlapping dates, only one status at any given time within a job):

```
                       Job    Status  User
Date / Time     
1/24/2011 10:58:04      1       A      Ted
1/24/2011 10:59:20      1       C      Bill
2/11/2011 6:53:14       1       A      Ted
2/11/2011 6:53:23       1       B      Max
2/15/2011 9:43:13       1       C      Bill
2/21/2011 15:24:42      1       F      Jim
3/2/2011 15:55:22       1       G      Phil Jr.
3/4/2011 14:57:45       1       H      Ted
3/7/2011 14:11:02       1       I      Jim
3/9/2011 9:57:34        1       J      Tim 
8/18/2014 11:59:35      2       A      Ted
8/18/2014 13:56:21      2       F      Bill
5/21/2015 9:30:30       2       G      Jim
6/5/2015 13:17:54       2       H      Jim
6/5/2015 14:40:38       2       I      Ted
6/9/2015 10:39:15       2       J      Tom
1/16/2015 7:45:58       3       A      Phil Jr.
1/16/2015 7:48:23       3       C      Jim
3/6/2015 14:09:42       3       A      Bill
3/11/2015 11:16:04      3       K      Jim
```

My initial thought (from the following link) was to groupby the job column, fill in the missing dates for each group and then ffill the statuses down.

[Pandas reindex dates in Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275540/pandas-reindex-dates-in-groupby/32275705#32275705)

I was able to make this work...kinda...if two statuses occurred on the same date, one would not be included in output and consequently some statuses were missing.

I then found the following, it supposedly handles the duplicate issue, but I am unable to get it to work with my data.

[Efficiently re-indexing one level with "forward-fill" in a multi-index dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356412/efficiently-re-indexing-one-level-with-forward-fill-in-a-multi-index-dataframe/29404203#29404203)

Am I on the right path thinking that filling in the missing dates and then ffill down the statuses is the correct way to ultimately capture daily counts of individual statuses?  Is there another method that might better use pandas features that I'm missing?

Comment: This sounds about right. The trick is definitely to just add up the ON and subtract the OFF for each day (where ON/OFF are for each A, B, C etc.).