# How do I fill in missing dates with zeros for a pandas groupby list?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I am looking to take a daily record of transactions and account for days when 0 transactions occurred.

Here is my initial dataframe:

```
df.head()
tr_timestamp  text      location
2016-01-01    cookies   TX
2016-01-01    pizza     TX
2016-01-04    apples    TX
2016-01-08    bread     TX
```

When I run a group by day, I get the following:

```
df_by_day = df['tr_timestamp'].groupby(df.tr_timestamp).count()
df_by_day

tr_timestamp
2016-01-01  2
2016-01-04  1
2016-01-08  1
```

I'm looking to use Python/Pandas where dates without a transaction are filled such that I get the following output:

```
df_by_day_filled

tr_timestamp
2016-01-01  2
2016-01-02  0
2016-01-03  0
2016-01-04  1
2016-01-05  0
2016-01-06  0
2016-01-07  0
2016-01-08  1
```

I've tried the following answers, which don't quite give the output I need returned:

[Pandas groupby for zero values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003100/pandas-groupby-for-zero-values)

[Fill Missing Dates in DataFrame with Duplicate Dates in Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900014/fill-missing-dates-in-dataframe-with-duplicate-dates-in-groupby)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [**`resample`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) operation:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.pop('tr_timestamp'))).resample('D')['text'].count()

tr_timestamp
2016-01-01    2
2016-01-02    0
2016-01-03    0
2016-01-04    1
2016-01-05    0
2016-01-06    0
2016-01-07    0
2016-01-08    1
Freq: D, Name: text, dtype: int64
```

The `pd.to_datetime` call ensures this works if "tr_timestamp" is not a datetime. If it is, then the solution simplifies to

```
df.dtypes

tr_timestamp    datetime64[ns]
text                    object
location                object
dtype: object

df.set_index('tr_timestamp').resample('D')['text'].count()

tr_timestamp
2016-01-01    2
2016-01-02    0
2016-01-03    0
2016-01-04    1
2016-01-05    0
2016-01-06    0
2016-01-07    0
2016-01-08    1
Freq: D, Name: text, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try:

```
df_by_day.asfreq('D', fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
tr_timestamp
2016-01-01    2
2016-01-02    0
2016-01-03    0
2016-01-04    1
2016-01-05    0
2016-01-06    0
2016-01-07    0
2016-01-08    1
Freq: D, Name: tr_timestamp, dtype: int64
```